# Free up space in Mail & Messaging after deleting mail accounts

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email, storage, nokia-lumia-730

I am using a Lumia 730 Windows Phone which I recently updated to Windows 10. The update is installed and the very next day it gives a message for more updates. When I try to install, my phone is out of phone storage. Now in order to free up some space I deleted my email accounts (all other than Microsoft). But I still can't see the space available and under Storage Mail & Messaging is still showing 800 MB. Any ideas how can I free up some more space from there?

Comment: 800mb for mail app is pretty weird! try this once ! remove all ur email accounts from outlook mail app, restart ur phone and check once in storage sense! if still, 800mb is intact, u gotta reset ur phone buddy!

Comment: Coudn't find anything else, had to reset the phone in the end which did the trick. Thanks. :)

Comment: Same issue here. I couldn't figure out how to free my 600Mb occupied by the email app.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend some steps to reduce your storage consumed by Mail & Messaging app.

1. Backup your SMS & MMS into SD card by using [Transfer My Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Transfer-my-Data/9WZDNCRFJ3DR)
   app by Microsoft. Delete the SMS and MMS on your phone. You can restore it using
   the same [Transfer My Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Transfer-my-Data/9WZDNCRFJ3DR) app after update.
2. Unlink Skype from Messaging app. Use [Skype](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/skype/9wzdncrfj364) app instead. It can be moved to SD card if needed.
3. Change your mail settings so that the Mail app will download only the email from last 3 days.
4. Restart your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I also have Lumia 730. You probably upgraded your phone from Windows 8.1. Go to storage app & see what is consuming more storage. Delete or uninstall some unwanted apps. Try moving some low duty apps (which you do not use every time or simply like a dictionary app) to SD card. Try moving songs, videos and photos to SD card. If you have upgraded to Windows 10 using Windows Insider production ring method. Try resetting your phone or wait for Redstone 1 update. It will probably have solution for this.

Comment: Rohit clearly said that Mail & Messaging is consuming 800MB. He wants to free up that space. Your answer clearly does not provide solution to his problem. Please read the question fully.

Comment: I think there is not any way to clear cached data of apps in Windows 10 Mobile. I said wait for Redstone 1 update. Also I said to reset phone. This is temporary solution. Main thing is clearing of cached data of apps. If you know any way to do this please tell. However I faced similar problem with Instagram (Beta) new app, which reached about 600 MB. I've  to uninstall it & again install it. Mail is system app it can't be uninstalled. So my is answer to wait for next update. If you know something else which is appropriate solution for this, then please tell.

Comment: `Free up space in Mail & Messaging after deleting mail accounts` is the question. The answer you provided does seem to be a general step in freeing up storage in phone. Please try to provide direct answer to the question before suggesting alternate workarounds. At least you could mention that there is no way and the only option is to reset your phone. But you mentioned `Go to storage app & see what is consuming more storage....` which was already told by the author that he did that.

Comment: `If you know something else which is appropriate solution for this, then please tell.` Don't take things too personal. I appreciate your contribution towards the community, its just that I want to correct you here so that you can contribute more to the community. This is a QA community where people ask questions about actual problems they face. It's important that we contributors understand the problem fully before answering it. Also relying your answer on chances of future update is not a good thing as well.

Comment: Thanks for your Guidance. I will take care about these things in future.